# Zxing crashes application on TollbarCaptureActivity

Tags: java, android, zxing

I implemented ToolbarCapture activity like this:

```
public class ToolbarCaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CaptureManager capture;
private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.capture_appcompat);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Scan Barcode");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    barcodeScannerView = (CompoundBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
    capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
    capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
    capture.decode();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    capture.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    capture.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    capture.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return barcodeScannerView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

The problem is, that when i try to run scanner with this class, application crashes with exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraInstance.setSurfaceHolder(android.view.SurfaceHolder)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview.startCameraPreview(CameraPreview.java:472)
                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview.startPreviewIfReady(CameraPreview.java:320)
                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview.access$200(CameraPreview.java:48)
                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview$1.surfaceChanged(CameraPreview.java:130)
                                                                      at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:618)
                                                                      at android.view.SurfaceView.setFrame(SurfaceView.java:308)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16691)
                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview.onLayout(CameraPreview.java:337)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16695)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2032)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195).*
```

The default BarcodeCaptureActivity works fine, exception is thrown only with activity with toolbar.
What's the problem?